# how to selecting all rows with all related objects(tables) in ormlite

Tags: android, ormlite

So i was wondering if its possible to select every row of a table including the other references to other tables(objects), something like:

```
class A{
    @DatabaseField  
    int somethingA; 
    @DatabaseField  
    String someStringA;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, foreign=true, foreignAutoRefresh=true)  
  >>  B instanceB;

    @ForeignCollectionField  
  >>  Collection< C > lotsOfCs;
}

class B{
    @DatabaseField  
    int somethingb; 
    @DatabaseField  
    String someStringB;
}

Classe C{
    @DatabaseField  
    int somethingC; 
    @DatabaseField  
    String someStringC;

    @DatabaseField( foreign=true, foreignAutoRefresh=true)  
   >> A instanceA;
}
```

So how can i select all rows of table/class A including the B and C objects, do i need to manually get B and C?

regards,

Comment: Hi! Gray, did you edited anything?

Comment: If you want me to see something, be sure to use @Gray, not just Gray.  That notifies me of the comment.  I reformatted the classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) does not use JOINs when it gets objects from the database so there is no way using one query to get results from multiple tables.

> do i need to manually get B and C?

Yes, although you *do* have the option to have ORMLite do it fore you in separate queries.  With `foreignAutoRefresh = true`, ORMLite will do a secondary query to refresh the `instanceB` field automatically when you get an `A`.  If you add an `eager = true` to the `lotsOfCs` foreign collection then that query also will be down before the `A` is created.

Comment: Thanks Gray, isn't there a button to automatically add the @ and the user name?

Comment: You mean in Stackoverflow?  I just start with the @Ma and then press tab and it completes for me.

Comment: if i press tab it will exit the cursor from the text field....:P. Anyway now i know that the user gets a message notification with the "@"username code. Thanks :)

Comment: Huh.  Tab works for me.  You don't know if there is a way to _know_ if the user gets the message @Maxrunner.  If you see the name in bold above the comment box, I suspect that's a good indication.

Comment: i was talking about email notifications.Using hte "@" will send the mail notification i think.